# Angular Production Build Could Not Find Plugin "proposal-numeric-separator"

Tags: angular, npm, angular8, npm-install, ng-build

When taking production build I am getting error like `Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it.` Here I have attached my error screenshot. We have added `"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",` in `dependencies` as well.

[image]

Comment: You might face [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17262)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue during angular 8 PROD build. Following has fixed in dev dependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23"    
"@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0"
```

Hope it helps.